Playwright API fixture gets timeout
I am trying to implement a fixtures helper file in Playwright so that certain data setup commands used by many tests can be better maintained v having all of these in every test spec that needs to create the same data. The same api call is working when placed within a test; however, when using it within a beforeEach hook, the POST call is made & gets a 200, but the test gets a timeout running the beforeEach hook. The POST is taking < 1s & I've set a timeout to 60s. I think I am having issues with the return in my fixture file. Not finding a ton of guidance. Would anyone be able to help identify where I've gone astray? Thanks for any assistance.
my fixture file:
const base = require('@playwright/test');
const randomFigures = Math.random().toString();

const randomAssetNumber = 'Asset' + randomFigures.substr(0, 8).toString()

// Extend base test by providing "postTruck".
// This new "test" can be used in multiple test files, and each of them will get the fixtures.
exports.test = base.test.extend({
    postTruck: async ({request}, use) => {
        return await request.post('https://myFullUrl.com/api/Truck', {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'ApiKey my-api-key'},
            data: {
                "ClientId": 1234,
                "AssetNumber": randomAssetNumber
            },
        })

    },

});
exports.expect = base.expect;

and then the test spec which uses above fixture:
const { test, expect } = require('../custom-commands/customFixtures');

test.beforeEach(async ({ request, postTruck }) => {
    const response = await postTruck(request);
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
});

test('basic test to see that beforeEach is used', async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
    console.log('my test is being run after beforeEach hook')
    await page.goto('/')
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(baseURL + '/Login.aspx')
})


Since https://myFullUrl.com/api/Truck isn't a thing, can you replace that with a mock API call that still reproduces the problem? Something like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users? If that doesn't repro the problem, then you'll need to share the relevant route from your API. Thanks.

You are calling the fixture like a function, which it isn't. You also forgot to use the fixture in the test, which caused the test to halt.
import { test as base, expect } from "@playwright/test";

const randomFigures = Math.random().toString();
const randomAssetNumber = "Asset" + randomFigures.substr(0, 8).toString();

const test = base.extend({
  postTruck: async ({ request }, use) => {
    const apiResponse = await request.get("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", );
    await use(apiResponse); // <--- pass the response to the test
  },
});

test.beforeEach(async ({ request, postTruck }) => {
  const response = postTruck;  // <-- using the fixture value
  expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
});

test("basic test to see that beforeEach is used", async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
  console.log("my test is being run after beforeEach hook");
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev");
  await expect(page).toHaveURL(/playwright/);
});



thank you very much for the reply. I am able to follow that setup to get both the beforeEach hook & test to work. I did have to comment out the status check within the beforeEach hook as it was throwing TypeError: response.status is not a function. That aside, I plan to use postTruck (& other similar data creation api calls) in a large number of spec files so I am wanting to find a path to keeping those api calls organized somewhere other than within each test spec. What adjustments should be made to do this?

got this working with separate file. still an issue to work through for assertions about that api response. but I will work through those now.

The "TypeError: response.status is not a function." is often due to an missing await.

thanks to @candre for help getting that cleaned up. adding the current state of my working beforeEach hook using an api call in a separate file since I have not found that design to be well represented in my playwright doc/example searches. I do still have some further things to work out to best include response assertions in particular. (Scrubbing urls again since they don't seem relevant to the test structure issues that I was running into).
customFixtures.js file
const { test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');

const randomFigures = Math.random().toString();
const randomAssetNumber = 'Asset' + randomFigures.substr(0, 8).toString()

exports.expect = expect

exports.test = test.extend({
    postTruck: async ({request}, use) => {
        const apiResponse = request.post('https://myFullUrl.com/api/Truck', {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'ApiKey my-api-key'},
            data: {
                "ClientId": 1234,
                "AssetNumber": randomAssetNumber
            },
        })
        await use(request) // thank you for this - was having problems figuring out where this needed to be
    },

});

and the test.spec.js calling that fixture in beforeEach hook which now passes:
const { test, expect } = require('../custom-commands/customFixtures');

test.beforeEach(async ({ postTruck }) => {
    const response = postTruck;  // <-- using the fixture value
    //expect(response.status()).toBe(200); 
    //gets Request context disposed so commented out & will research fixing that piece.
});

test("basic test to see that beforeEach is used", async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
    console.log("my test is being run after beforeEach hook");
    await page.goto("https://playwright.dev");
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/playwright/);
});

this ChecklyHQ video was helpful also. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O7dyz6XO2s
